# Can't convert Json to pandas df

Tags: python, json, pandas

It should be easy but I couldn't figure out how to convert the following json file to pandas df after one hour trying:
https://www.sec.gov/files/company_tickers_exchange.json

It has following uncommon format:

```
{"fields":["cik","name","ticker","exchange"],"data":[[320193,"Apple Inc.","AAPL","Nasdaq"],[789019,"MICROSOFT CORP","MSFT","Nasdaq"],[1652044,"Alphabet...
```

The DF should have following columns:

```
cik, name, ticker, exchange
```

The entries underneath it would be:

```
320193,"Apple Inc.","AAPL","Nasdaq"
789019,"MICROSOFT CORP","MSFT","Nasdaq"
...
```

Together it would look like:

```
cik     name            ticker      exchange
320193  Apple Inc.      AAPL        Nasdaq
789019  MICROSOFT CORP  MSFT        Nasdaq
...
```

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Start by  posing a VALID json doc. Explain how the df should look like

Comment: Since `fields` is 1-dimensional, while `data` is 2-dimensional, how do you expect them to be put into the resulting df?

Comment: @Barmar I have edited my questions to answer your questions...

Comment: @gunardilin - just follow my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just point to the `data` section inside your json.
The `data` in the code below is a subset of the actual data.

```
import pandas as pd

data = [[320193,"Apple Inc.","AAPL","Nasdaq"],[789019,"MICROSOFT CORP","MSFT","Nasdaq"],[1652044,"Alphabet Inc.","GOOG","Nasdaq"],[1018724,"AMAZON COM INC","AMZN","Nasdaq"],[1326801,"Facebook Inc","FB","Nasdaq"]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['id','name','short_name','other'])
print(df)
```

output

```
        id            name short_name   other
0   320193      Apple Inc.       AAPL  Nasdaq
1   789019  MICROSOFT CORP       MSFT  Nasdaq
2  1652044   Alphabet Inc.       GOOG  Nasdaq
3  1018724  AMAZON COM INC       AMZN  Nasdaq
4  1326801    Facebook Inc         FB  Nasdaq
```